# page url in shortcode

Tags: widgets, urls, shortcode

I have a problem.

I'm using a custom shortcode to try to get the url. If the shortcode is inside a post then it gets the post url. When I open the post on a category list, this post shortcode works correctly.

```
extract(shortcode_atts(array(
    'gurl'  => get_permalink(),
), $atts));
```

But when i try to add this shortcode in widget text, I get the last post url.

Tell me please how I can get the post url when the shortcode is in a widget.

Comment: Is this for archive pages, single views, both?

Comment: @mrwweb this problem have place on archive page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how the page's query and loop are constructed, when you access the post object from the sidebar or footer, you sometimes get the last post in the loop rather than the page itself.

You can ensure you're getting the original (page) object by running [wp_reset_query()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_query) from inside your widget (before you access the post object or run any functions that assume the current post as their target).

One caveat here: make sure there's nothing *after* your widget that would be affected by this post reset.

Answer (score 0):

`get_permalink()` without a Post ID specified should be used inside `The Loop`.

You can use it outside `The Loop`, but you have to pass an ID (`get_permalink($id)`).

How you get that ID is up to you, and dependant on your exact scenario.

For further information, please see the following -

- The [Function Reference for `get_permalink()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_permalink).
- The [Codex for `The Loop`](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop).